# Matching vectors by last element

Tags: r, list, vector

I am wondering how can I join list of vectors to a data.frame or just to vectors to append new item to each vector with a match.

```
# list of vectors that should be extended with values from vp
# based on last item match to vc
lst <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), 
        c("b", "d"), 
        c("f", "e")
   )

vc <- c("c", "c", "d")
vp <- c("k", "l", "m")

# expected output:
expect <- list (c("a", "b", "c", "k"), 
                c("a", "b", "c", "l"), 
                c("b", "d", "m"), 
                c("f", "e"))
```

It is worth noticing that if last item in `lst` matches several values in `vc`, vector is duplicated. Vector stays unchanged if it does not match values in `vc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
L <- lapply(lst, function(v) vp[vc %in% v[length(v)]])
pv <- function(v1, v2) {
      if (length(v2) == 0) {
        list(v1)
      }
      else {
        lapply(v2, function(v) c(v1,v))
      }
}
L2 <- mapply(pv, lst, L)
unlist(L2, recursive=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
l=lapply(lst, function(v) vp[vc %in% v])
res=sapply(1:length(lst), function(i) 
        {
            x=lst[[i]]
            y=l[[i]]
            if (length(y)>0)
                sapply(1:length(y), function(j)  list(c(x, y[j])))
            else
                list(x)
        }
    )
unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)
```